# absolute vs relative element positioning within a website

Tags: css, positioning

so I know pretty much how absolute/relative positioning works and have used it quite extensively in the past. Right now, I do have a website, where I need to position a graphical element so that it 'sticks' to the bottom, regardless of the website/screen dimensions.

I was able to do that for my own screen size, but whenever the height is different (larger), the elements (2 red images, as seen in the example) just 'float' in the middle of the site, instead of the bottom where it should be.

[Here's the site](http://www.viewlike.us/operator/#u=http://fldesign.sk/B00268899_A1/index)

And the code:

```
    <div class='fimage'>
    </div>
    <div class='fimage2'>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
    .fimage{
        background-image: url(img/fimage.png);
        height: 236px;
        width: 50%;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        float: left;
}

.fimage2{
        background-image: url(img/fimage2.png);
        height: 236px;
        width: 50%;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        float: right;
}
```

Note that i have 2 separate images positioned left/right. The code is without any positioning now, because I wasn't able to figure it out correctly and always just messed up the whole layout.

Could you give me suggestions on how to position the elements, so they stay right at the bottom?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kill the floats and position them absolutely, with the bottom and right (or left) set to 0.

```
.fimage {
    background-image: url(img/fimage.png);
    height: 236px;
    width: 50%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
}
.fimage2 {
    background-image: url(img/fimage2.png);
    height: 236px;
    width: 50%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    right:0;
}
```

Comment: thanks. That seems to do something, but it's still not 100% working.. first, I had to adjust the position of the right bit, as it was floating somewhere in the middle (now I mean horizontally)   
    .fimage2 {
    background-image: url(img/fimage2.png);
    height: 236px;
    width: 510px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    right:0%;
}
And when I shorten the height of the site too much, it doesn't stay at the bottom either. But I think that should be acceptable.